# Error page for Javascript Error in MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

In my MVC application I am using custom error attribute class inherited from HandleErrorAttribute to globally handle the exceptions.

My objective is :

1. Showing error page while exception occurred.
2. Showing a custom error page.

In my application most of the control action method are called using Ajax.I am able to show the error page when exception occurs for those controller action where Ajax call is not used but in the case of Ajax call error is logged but error page is not displaying.

Comment: Ajax call never redirect (the whole point of making an ajax call is to stay on the **same** page)

Comment: You can redirect to page in ajax error function